# How to delete all properties of a type JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following object in my code.

```
    [
{
"Name": "John Johnsson",
"Adress": "Linkoping",
"Id": 0,
"Age": "43",
"Role": "Software Engineer"
},
{
"Name": "Marcus Svensson",
"Adress": "Norrköping",
"Age": "26",
"Id": 1,
"Role": "Project Manager"
},
{
"Age": "25",
"Name": "Trevor McNoah",
"Id": 2,
"Adress": "Stockholm",
"Role": "CTO"
}
]
```

How do I best delete all the "Adress" fields? So I end up with the following result. I've been struggling to find an answer to this basic question.

```
[
{
"Name": "John Johnsson",
"Id": 0,
"Age": "43",
"Role": "Software Engineer"
},
{
"Name": "Marcus Svensson",
"Age": "26",
"Id": 1,
"Role": "Project Manager"
},
{
"Age": "25",
"Name": "Trevor McNoah",
"Id": 2,
"Role": "CTO"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has `delete` operator:

```js
data.forEach(item => {
  delete item['Address'];
})
```

You can read more about delete operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that: so you don't mutate the initial array.

```
const listWithoutAddress = list.map(({Adress, ...rest}) => ({...rest}));
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove a property from a js object you can use the delete command, like this:

```js
let arr =  [
{
"Name": "John Johnsson",
"Address": "Linkoping",
"Id": 0,
"Age": "43",
"Role": "Software Engineer"
},
{
"Name": "Marcus Svensson",
"Address": "Norrköping",
"Age": "26",
"Id": 1,
"Role": "Project Manager"
},
{
"Age": "25",
"Name": "Trevor McNoah",
"Id": 2,
"Address": "Stockholm",
"Role": "CTO"
}
];

console.log(arr);

arr.forEach(_=>{delete _.Address}); // <-- this is it

console.log(arr);
```